# Bind vector in textview sides programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, vector

I'm trying to migrate my `.png's` to vector using `appcompat` for versions less than 
lollipop, and i need to bind drawable start to textview with `.xml` of vector.

How i can set vector in drawableStart of my `textview` dynamically?

To png i use `.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`, but it crash with vector...